# Use screencapture to snap just a single window that may not be in focus in an interval in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, screenshot, screen-capture

I have this so far

```
while [ 1 ];do vardate=$(date +%d\-%m\-%Y\_%H.%M.%S); screencapture -t jpg -x ~/Desktop/screenshots/$vardate.jpg; sleep 30; done
```

But I want to capture just one window, even if its not in focus so I can work elsewhere (another desktop, monitor, etc) but it just keeps snapping one window.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use:

```
screencapture -l<window id>
```

Which I believe will snap your window. You need the Window ID, which can be obtained from the task manager.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't seem to find the window id. By task manager I assume you mean activity monitor but I can't seem to find it in there. Any tips?

Comment: @Oscar WID's can be found using Quartz Debug (available here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) Also there are commands that could find the WID, but those are kinda sketchy